# Как сделать так, чтобы анимация зарядки отключалась через некоторое время?

Tags: android, файлы, анимация, файловая-система, прошивка

Как сделать так, чтобы после подключения зарядки и воспроизведения анимации зарядки, она отключалась, к примеру, секунд через 10?

Система: Android 13

OС: ArrowOS

Никакие действия не проводил

Comment: Причем тут [файлы] и [файловая система]?